# Disabling modules for frontend requests?

Tags: frontend, performance

In order to increase performance for a site I'm looking to disable modules from being loaded *only* if it is a frontend request (i.e. not admin).

Has anyone had experience doing this, or have any suggestions on how to go about this?

Comment: what kind of issue you figured out with that extension, for my experience if you extension does not do anything that occupies memory, it is not a big problem for performance.

Answer (score 2):

Do you only want to disable the frontend output? In that case you can disable the extension in System > Configuration > Advanced > Advanced. This will only disable the frontend output, f.e. blocks.

Comment: no, i want to completely not load certain modules

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is the best (and only) way to do this. Or you have to disable the extension completely bij editing the app/etc/modules/My_Module.xml file and set active to false.